# Can't Download sbt-plugin 2.5.4 using activator on OSX platform

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

I had it working in Ubuntu but,

I can't seem to compile the play scala project in my mac OS sierra. I manually install activator-dist-1.3.12 and add activator bin's path in /etc/paths.

I got this error:

```
$ activator compile

[info] Loading project definition from /Volumes/carldrive/workspace/Documents/knowledge-base/knowledge-base-api/project
[info] Updating {file:/Volumes/carldrive/workspace/Documents/knowledge-base/knowledge-base-api/project/}knowledge-base-api-build...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.5.4 ...
[error] Server access Error: Operation timed out (Connection timed out) url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Operation timed out (Connection timed out) url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Operation timed out (Connection timed out) url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Operation timed out (Connection timed out) url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.5.4
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/calot/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.5.4/sbt-plugin-2.5.4.pom
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   /Volumes/carldrive/workspace/bin/activator-dist-1.3.12/repository/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   /Volumes/carldrive/workspace/bin/activator-dist-1.3.12/repository/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-releases-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugins-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== maven-central: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/2.5.4/sbt-plugin-2.5.4.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.11 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you will be able to build this project on clean Ubuntu (or after cleaning SBT cache) . The `https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml` is absent, you can view the structure on `https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/maven-releases/com/typesafe/play/`, yes `https://repo.typesafe.com` redirects to `https://dl.bintray.com`

So, the `sbt-plugin` now in the `https://dl.bintray.com/playframework/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml`. It looks like [The official documentation not yet fixed](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/NewApplication)

I propose you to use Binatry repo (it works for me)

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("owner", "repo")

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")
```

Comment: I have something like resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases" and I change it to the one you suggest in build.sbt but I still got the same error.

Comment: I tried to ping dl.bintray.com but it is a timeout.

Comment: Can you open (download) [https://dl.bintray.com/playframework/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml](https://dl.bintray.com/playframework/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.5.4/ivys/ivy.xml) ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't download. The site can't be reached.

Comment: It is a good news, I have a mac OS and I can reach this URL. So the problem is in your network - proxy, firewall or some other thing.

Comment: you are right, I did a retry and it finally work. There might be something wrong with the repository site that hinder me downloading the artifactories.